# Logic puzzle and Chat GPT

Tags: logic

I've asked a logic puzzle to `Chat GPT` to see whether my reasoning is correct around a logic puzzle.

The puzzle is the following:

> You are on an island with either Honestant who always speak the truth
> or Swindlecants who always lie. An islander approaches you and tells
> you "On this island there's a treasure only if I'm an Honestant".
> Should you go and find the treasure?

**I believe the solution is that you should go to find the treasure in all instances** whether the speaker is a Honestant or a Swindlecant.
It's trivial if he is an Honestant, but you can derive there's a treasure if he is Swindlecant too: *because the whole proposition have to be a lie and being the second part false, the former must be true*.

I would like to know:

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. Could `Chat GPT` write a correct solution if I would have asked it differently?
3. Is `Chat GPT` correct to criticize that in this context not a Swindlecant is different from Honestant?
4. Could you highlight any logical mistake / fallacy?

Thanks in advance!

The following is the transcription of the dialogue that took place:

Fredo:

> You are on an island with either Honestant who always speak the truth
> or Swindlecants who always lie. An islander approaches you and tells
> you "On this island there's a treasure only if I'm an Honestant".
> Should you go and find the treasure?

Chat GPT:

> In this situation, you should go and find the treasure. Here's why:
> The islander tells you that there is a treasure on the island only if
> he is an Honestant. Since he is either an Honestant or a Swindlecant,
> and he is making a statement about himself, this means that if he is
> an Honestant, then what he says is true, and if he is a Swindlecant,
> then what he says is false. If the islander is an Honestant, then his
> statement that there is a treasure on the island only if he is an
> Honestant is true. This means that there is a treasure on the island.
> On the other hand, if the islander is a Swindlecant, then his
> statement that there is a treasure on the island only if he is an
> Honestant is false. This means that there is no treasure on the
> island. Since the islander's statement is true if he is an Honestant
> and false if he is a Swindlecant, this means that if there is a
> treasure on the island, then the islander is an Honestant, and if
> there is no treasure on the island, then the islander is a
> Swindlecant.

Fredo:

> Even if the islander is a Swindlecant the treasure exist, because he
> would be telling a lie in case he says "there's a treasure only if I'm
> not a Swindlecant"

Chat GPT:

> That's an interesting interpretation of the puzzle, but it doesn't
> quite fit with the original statement. In the original statement, the
> islander says that there is a treasure on the island only if he is an
> Honestant, not if he is not a Swindlecant. If the islander were to say
> that there is a treasure on the island only if he is not a
> Swindlecant, then the logic of the puzzle would be different. In that
> case, if the islander is an Honestant, then his statement would be
> false, which means that there would be no treasure on the island. On
> the other hand, if the islander is a Swindlecant, then his statement
> would be true, which means that there would be a treasure on the
> island.

Fredo:

> Well in this context Honestant is equal to not Swindlecant

Chat GPT:

> In the context of this puzzle, "Honestant" and "not Swindlecant" are
> not the same thing. An Honestant is someone who always tells the
> truth, whereas "not Swindlecant" means that someone is not a
> Swindlecant, which could mean that they are an Honestant or something
> else.

Fredo:

> You forgot that I told you that a islander can only be either of those
> two states

Chat GPT:

> Yes, you did mention that an islander can only be either an Honestant
> or a Swindlecant. This is an important piece of information for
> solving the puzzle, because it means that the islander's statement is
> either true or false, depending on whether he is an Honestant or a
> Swindlecant.

Fredo:

> Therefore if you know that an islander can only be either an Honestant
> or a Swindlecant it's correct to say that Honestant is equivalent to
> not Swindlecant, right?

Chat GPT:

> In the context of this puzzle, "Honestant" and "not Swindlecant" are
> not equivalent. "Honestant" refers to someone who always tells the
> truth, whereas "not Swindlecant" refers to someone who is not a
> Swindlecant, which could mean that they are an Honestant or something
> else.

Fredo:

> I told you that a person can only be one or the other state, and have
> to be in a state. There are not undefined islanders! So if I tell you
> an islander is not Honestant you can infer that he is Swindlecant and
> viceversa, OK?!

Chat GPT:

> Yes, you did mention that an islander can only be either an Honestant
> or a Swindlecant, and that there are no undefined islanders.
>
> You are correct that if you know that an islander is not an Honestant,
> you can infer that he is a Swindlecant, and vice versa. This is
> because, as you mentioned, an islander can only be one of these two
> states, and there are no undefined islanders.

Fredo:

> OK, now that you admitted that, can you also admit that the treasure
> is on the island even if who is saying the phrase "There's a tresure
> only if I'm Honestant" is a Swindlecant?

Chat GPT:

> In the original puzzle, the islander says that there is a treasure on
> the island only if he is an Honestant. This means that if the islander
> is an Honestant, then his statement is true, and if he is a
> Swindlecant, then his statement is false.
>
> If the islander is an Honestant, then his statement that there is a
> treasure on the island only if he is an Honestant is true. This means
> that there is a treasure on the island.
>
> On the other hand, if the islander is a Swindlecant, then his
> statement that there is a treasure on the island only if he is an
> Honestant is false. This means that there is no treasure on the
> island.
>
> Therefore, in the original puzzle, the presence or absence of a
> treasure on the island depends on whether the islander is an Honestant
> or a Swindlecant. If the islander is an Honestant, then there is a
> treasure on the island, and if the islander is a Swindlecant, then
> there is no treasure on the island.
>
> In your variation of the puzzle, where the islander says that there is
> a treasure on the island only if he is not a Swindlecant, the logic is
> different. In that case, if the islander is an Honestant, then his
> statement would be false, which means that there would be no treasure
> on the island. On the other hand, if the islander is a Swindlec

*Chat GPT stopped working*

Comment: This is too long.  If he is lying then the claim "Treasure $\implies$ Honest" must be False.  If there is No Treasure, then the claim is vacuously true, hence it is not False.  So there must be a Treasure.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: What do you mean by vacuously true?

Comment: @aschepler why?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut you are saying honestant -> treasure while the former user that replied said treasure -> honestant.
From my understanding when you use A only-if B you mean A -> B, instead when you say A if B you mean B -> A. Can you clarify?

Comment: You are right, I got it wrong. The statement is the implication "There is a treasure $\implies$ I'm a Honestant". If the guy is a Swindlecant, the implication is true if there is no treasure, and false otherwise. Therefore, if he is a swidlecant, the implication is wrong and there is a treasure. $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $B\vee \neg A$, and if $B$ is false this is equivalent to $\neg A$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut therefore the user that said "Both of you are missing" was wrong, and I'm indeed right?
What can you say about what the first user wrote?

Comment: @aschepler  Why is that?  If there is treasure, and our man is a Liar, then the claim "Treasure $\implies$ Honest" is a Lie, consistent with the speaker's nature.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I believe @aschepler made the same mistake as in my previous comment, i.e. interpret the statement as "I'm a Honestant $\implies$ There is a treasure", which is impossible if he is a Swindlecant (because then the statement is true).

Comment: @FredoCorleone  An implication is vacuously true if its premise is False.  Thus the statement "Any Integer between $1.4$ and $1.5$  is greater than $100$" is vacuously True because there are no such integers.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Saying "$A$ *only if* $B$" is equivalent to "$A\implies B$". It says nothing whatsoever about whether $B$ might imply $A$ or not.   Saying "$A$ *if* $B$" would be equivalent to "$B\implies A$" but that's not what appears here.

Comment: @lulu infact but you can say that !b -> !a and that makes the problem clearer because you end up with If not honest then not treasure which is not the case as the Swindlecant must be lying and therefore there's a treasure

Comment: Now that we established the solution, is Chat GPT correct in its critique on the fact that I couldn't tell that not Honestant is Swindlecant and viceversa? I think that with the phrasing either A or B I could say that not A is B, or am I being a fool here?

Comment: I'm not going to read the dialog because, as I mentioned, it is too long.  I read the first analysis but could not follow it.  The system appears to believe that it is possible that there is a Treasure and possible that there isn't in which case I don't understand why it recommends that you go look for it.  But perhaps I am simply misreading what it says.

Comment: I won't comment on ChatGPT output. If you have questions about this, ask OpenAI. Tests I have made show it's very easy to get wrong answers from it (in one case, that $2$ and $4$ are not integers). I'm not going to investigate this further. IMO, ChatGPT output should just be banned from all questions and answers on all of the SE network.

Comment: Any idea on why I've been downvoted?

Comment: @FredoCorleone The downvotes are probably either because the question is very long, or due to negative attitudes towards the idea of ChatGPT.

Comment: This question is fundamentally built on an incorrect assumption:  namely, that ChatGPT is, in any way, trained to reason.  It is not.  It strings words together in a way that is similar to the way in which English writers write.  It does not think or reason---it is all syntax, no semantics.  As such, I don't think that there is anything to be learned here. (-1)

Comment: Moreover, the mathematical content of this question appears to be a fairly standard "Knights & Knaves" problem.  [puzzling.se] has [an entire tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars?tab=Newest) for these.  The "novelty" here seems to be the use of ChatGPT which seems to add nothing of mathematical interest to the problem.

Comment: @XanderHenderson does it have to be a novelty or cutting edge math stuff? Guys if you are going to downvote every math noob asking for stuff he couldn't find after a legit search you will end up with a sterile environment where people are afraid to ask things just because it's ure you are going to downvote.

Comment: @FredoCorleone "Novel", in this case, means "this question has not been asked here before".  Questions which are not novel are typically closed as duplicates.  In this case, I see nothing in this question which hasn't been asked on the network before---if you want your logic puzzle solved, I would suggest that you look at other similar problems, either here or on [puzzling.se].  The inclusion of the ChatGPT transcript is a distraction, which has no mathematical content.

Comment: "IMO, ChatGPT output should just be banned from all questions and answers on all of the SE network." I fully agree !

Comment: Just one additional remark to the "vacous truth". This is used different in mathematics and in daily life. If I tell someone : "All the planes I have are Pipers" this is mathematically true , if I in reality do not have a plane, but everyone would assume that I do have at least one plane because otherwise this statement is meaningless.

Comment: @XanderHenderson a recent paper has demonstrated that LLMs possess zero-shot reasoning capabilities, challenging the assumption you made in your earlier message ending with (-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to start, it's worth noting that ChatGPT is trained based on language and conversations, and so its ability to solve math or logic problems is unreliable.

The tricky thing about this problem is that "There's a treasure only if I'm an Honestant" logically means something different than what you may expect. "Being an honestant" is the necessary condition, and "treasure existing" is the sufficient condition. This is represented as $$Treasure \implies Honest$$ (and not the other way around).

It seems like the rest of the solution is given in the comments, so I will focus on clearing up your secondary question.

You are **correct** that given the phrasing of "Everyone is either an Honestant or Swindlecant", "not Swindlecant" does indeed imply "Honestant". In formal logic, this idea of "A or B, not A, therefore B" is a rule of deduction called "disjunctive syllogism". Since there is no third option, anyone who isn't a Swindlecant is indeed an Honestant.

It is also the case that conversely, "Honestant" implies "not Swindlecant". The problem does not explicitly state that nobody is both an Honestant and a Swindlecant, but due to the definition of those words, it is clearly impossible for anyone to both at once, since that would mean they simultaneously "always speak the truth" and "always lie".

Comment: I've used the construct either X or Y which should be XOR I guess, am I wrong?

Comment: "Either" is sometimes used to indicate XOR, but it's not usually the convention. ("or" is usually assumed as inclusive). In this case it doesn't matter though as it is pretty clear that one cannot be both an Honestant and a Swindlecant.

Answer (score 1):

Like politicians, these Chat AI's are becoming a real nuisance! They talk a lot, and what they say sounds good enough for many people to trust and believe them, but a little bit of analysis shows that they are just doing word association without any logic. So you get a lot of misplaced trust. Not good!

Here's my analysis:

> If the islander is an Honestant, then his
> statement that there is a treasure on the island only if he is an
> Honestant is true. This means that there is a treasure on the island.

No.  We get that the statement $Treasure \to Honestant$ is True, and we would also have $Honestant$. $Treasure$ does not follow from that. Indeed, we cannot infer from this puzzle that there is treasure.

> On the other hand, if the islander is a Swindlecant, then his
> statement that there is a treasure on the island only if he is an
> Honestant is false. This means that there is no treasure on the
> island.

Also wrong. Now we have that $Treasure \to Honestant$ is False, and $Honestant$ is also False. If we were to use the classical truth-functional analysis of the conditional, we get that $Treasure$ is True, rather than False. And if you don't want to use the truth-functional analysis, nothing can be concluded as far as $Treasure$ goes at all. Indeed, from this puzzle we can neither conclude that there is treasure nor that there isn't treasure.

> Since the islander's statement is true if he is an Honestant
> and false if he is a Swindlecant, this means that if there is a
> treasure on the island, then the islander is an Honestant, and if
> there is no treasure on the island, then the islander is a
> Swindlecant.

First part incorrect. Chat GPT goes from $Honestant \to (Treasure \to Honestant)$ to $Treasure \to Honestant$, but that does not follow.  Also, how would this even help with the ultimate goal of trying to figure out whether there is Treasure or not?

Second part also incorrect. Now Chat GPT says that from $SwindleCantant \to \neg (Treasure \to Honestant)$ and $\neg Treasure$ we can infer $Swindlecant$, but this is not valid either. And again, how would this even help?

At the end of the first paragraph, Chat GPT has not established that there is $Treasure$, even if the first couple of inferences were correct. And again, the other two inferences aren't even relevant towards this goal.

The second paragraph is even worse:

> If the islander were to say
> that there is a treasure on the island only if he is not a
> Swindlecant, then the logic of the puzzle would be different. In that
> case, if the islander is an Honestant, then his statement would be
> false, which means that there would be no treasure on the island. On
> the other hand, if the islander is a Swindlecant, then his statement
> would be true, which means that there would be a treasure on the
> island.

Nope. If the islander is an Honestant, then the statement is still true. That's what Honestants do: tell the truth. And even if the statement 'there is a treasure on the island only if he is not a Swindlecant' is false, it still doesn't follow that there is no treasure. Likewise, if the islander is a Swindlecant, then the statement is false, not true. And even if it were true, it does not imply that there is treasure.

Finally, in the whole discussion of 'not Swindlecant' vs 'Honestant', ChatGPT is clearly mistaken as well. Sure, anyone who sometimes speaks the truth and somtimes lies is neoither an Honestant nor a Swindlecant, so maybe that was the point ChatGPT was trying to make, but *in the context of this puzzle* (using Chat GOT's exact words), it was clear that any islander was an Honestant or a Swindlecant, so any islander who is not an Honestant is a Swindlecant, period.

In sum, ChatGPT did not make a single correct inference. And in the last paragraph, ChatGPT simply repeats what it already said. Proof Ad Nauseam?  Well, that's a fallacy too.